# Plotting a cloud of points with a color gradient in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix with values between `0` and `1`.

The matrix goes from `(1,1,1)` to `(k,k,k)`. For example, `M(3,2,5) = 0.25`.

I want to plot this matrix in a 3D graph as a cloud of points, where each point will be colored with a gradient from transparent (`0`) to black or other color (`1`).

I'm not sure if you can use alpha in matlab... if not, then `0` will be just white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scatter3` with values from your matrix specifying the color of the point, and a white to black gradient would give you the same effect as transparency if the background is white. If you have a matrix `M` of size `[k k k]` To get the `x,y,z` for your points you can use `ind2sub` as follows:

```
>>[x,y,z] = ind2sub([k k k],1:numel(M));
```

And you can use `scatter3` with this x,y,z as:

```
>>colors = [M(1:end)]'*[1 1 1]; % Get colors from black to white 
>>scatter3(x,y,z,36,colors);
```